# How can I change the ToTitle function to be a string extension?

Tags: c#

I recently saw a post asking if there was a way to change a string so it started with an uppercase and had lowercase following. Here looks to be the best solution:

```
public static class StringHelper {     
   public static string ToTitleCase(string text)     {
      return StringHelper.ToTitleCase(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);     
   }         
   public static string ToTitleCase(string text, CultureInfo cultureInfo)     {         
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return string.Empty;             
      TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;         
      return textInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());     
   } 
}
```

What I would like is to convert these into string extensions. Can someone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: You should use CurrentCulture rather than InvariantCulture when the culture is not specified

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword in front of the first parameter:

```
public static class StringHelper
{     
   public static string ToTitleCase(this string text)
   {
      return StringHelper.ToTitleCase(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);     
   }         

   public static string ToTitleCase(this string text, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   {         
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return string.Empty;             
      TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;         
      return textInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());     
   } 
}
```

See [How to: Implement and Call a Custom Extension Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class StringHelper {     
   public static string ToTitleCase(**this** string text)     {
      return StringHelper.ToTitleCase(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);     
   }         
   public static string ToTitleCase(**this** string text, CultureInfo cultureInfo)     {         
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return string.Empty;             
      TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;         
      return textInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());     
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change method signature to:

```
  public static string ToTitleCase(this string text) { ...
```